# blank pdf file using TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

This is my first post on SO, I hope I get this right.

I have a column in a mySQL database that contains HTML. I retrieve this content using the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT html_content FROM my_table WHERE sent_flag = 0";

$statement = $con->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();

$array = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
unset($statement);

$html = $array[0][0];
```

I know that I am getting the contents of the column in the table because I can echo it (yes, I know that TCPDF can only have output to the .pdf file, I just echoed it to make sure the contents were in $html)

I write the contents as follows:

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('times','','12','','false');

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

This results in an empty .pdf file. What is strange I can copy the contents from the column using phpMyAdmin and assign it directly to $html and the .pdf file creates fine. Any suggestions as to what is happening and how to correct it are greatly appreciated.

Also, if I just do a Write like this:

```
$pdf->Write(0, $html, '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```

I do get a .pdf file complete with html tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 0, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT,true);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        @$pdf->writeHTML($html);
        $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i was able to get it functioning by running it through tidy.